# Gerenciar versões bibliotecas android

Tags: android, android-studio

Atualmente no meu aplicativo possuo os seguintes `imports` de bibliotecas no meu `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
```

1. O que definitivamente o :+ faz?
2. Ele traz a última versão disponível no celular que irá rodar o app?
3. Ou que existe no meu Android Studio no momento da compilação?

Eu tenho tido problemas, por exemplo, com alguns clientes com celulares mais antigos, o qual o serviço de mapas não tem funcionado de forma perfeita, pelo fato do *Google Play Services* não estar atualizado..
Atualmente o `compileSDKVersion` do meu *App* é o `26`

Answer (score 1):

A utilização de versões dinâmicas é uma funcionalidade do Gradle, e [está documentada no site deles](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:dynamic_versions_and_changing_modules):

> If the dependency is declared as a dynamic version (like 1.+), Gradle
> will resolve this to the newest available static version (like 1.2) in
> the repository. For Maven repositories, this is done using the
> maven-metadata.xml file, while for Ivy repositories this is done by
> directory listing.
>
> [...]
>
> Once each repository has been inspected for the module, Gradle will choose the 'best' one to use. This is done using the following criteria:
>
> For a dynamic version, a 'higher' static version is preferred over a 'lower' version.

Em **tempo de compilação** do projeto o Gradle irá traduzir o `+` para a última versão que ele encontrar nos repositórios acessíveis.

Então quando você instala o app está versão já foi definida.

---

A forma que acontece a interação entre a biblioteca cliente e o APK instalado nos smartphones [está descrita no site do Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview).

> The client library contains the interfaces to the individual Google services and allows you to obtain authorization from users to gain access to these services with their credentials. It also contains APIs that allow you to resolve any issues at runtime, such as a missing, disabled, or out-of-date Google Play services APK. The client library has a light footprint if you use ProGuard as part of your build process, so it won't have an adverse impact on your app's file size.
>
> [...]
>
> The Google Play services APK contains the individual Google services and runs as a background service in the Android OS. You interact with the background service through the client library and the service carries out the actions on your behalf. An easy-to-use authorization flow is also provided to gain access to the each Google service, which provides consistency for both you and your users.

---

Utilizar a última versão do Play Services oferece a vantagem de sempre ter disponíveis as novas funcionalidades e atualizações de segurança.

Mas, como você percebeu isso tem um preço. **A biblioteca cliente precisa rodar em conjunto com uma versão compatível do Google Services APK**.

---

### Resumindo

Da forma que você descreveu, **sempre** que **você** compilar seu app e o Gradle encontrar uma nova versão do Play Services, ele a utilizará. Seu usuário então deverá ter uma versão compatível do Google Services APK instalado no smartphone dele.

A pergunta que você deve se fazer é: **É absolutamente necessário pro meu aplicativo sempre utilizar a última versão do Google Play Services?**

A resposta é quase sempre **não**. **Usar a última versão é quase sempre desnecessário**, exceto em caso de atualizações de segurança ou novas funcionalidades indispensáveis.

Minha recomendação é que você escolha uma versão fixa e utilize-a, atualizando somente conforme necessário.

---

Nota: no geral, qualquer tipo de dependência dinâmica pode trazer problemas, não somente a do Play Services. [Evite-as sempre que possível](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/09/09/dont-use-dynamic-versions-for-your-dependencies/).